# How to input data in website where HTML tag present inside Iframe?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to input data into a table fields in webpage using vba, but I am unable to access any elements present in Iframe Tag.

Website Tags:

unable to access any elements inside this frame.

I tried to access using frames method

```
Dim elemCollection As IHTMLElementCollection
Set elemCollection = ie.Document.frames("patmainFrame").Document.all
```

Here I am able to locate the Frame however I am unable to figure out how to access HTML elements inside a frame there is a dropdown that I want to select and insert that within a text box.

Answer (score 0):

Finally located an way to access a webpage frame using the following declarations

```
Sub test()       
Dim workFrame As HTMLIFrame        
Dim objShell As Object, oWin As Object              
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument    
Dim ie As InternetExplorer  `enter code here`
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set IE_Doc = ie.Document              
Set workFrame = ie.Document.getElementById("XXXXXX")            
Set HTMLDoc = workFrame.contentWindow.Document   
'do something... perform an action   
'.........      
'.........    
End Sub
```

Thank You.